# Can not install sentry on-premise using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sentry

I trying to install Sentry using helm [chart](https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/tree/develop/sentry)
But error occurs when installing Sentry using the Helm chart: I don't know what the problem is.

This is my helm version and error log

```
helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.10.2", GitCommit:"50f003e5ee8704ec937a756c646870227d7c8b58", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.19.3"}
```

```
~/sentry> helm install sentry sentry/sentry -f values.yaml --debug
install.go:192: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:209: [debug] CHART PATH: /Users/pansukkim/Library/Caches/helm/repository/sentry-17.8.0.tgz

coalesce.go:175: warning: skipped value for kafka.config: Not a table.
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "sentry-sentry-secret" Secret
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:128: [debug] creating 61 resource(s)
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "sentry-db-check" Job
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:540: [debug] Watching for changes to Job sentry-db-check with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: ADDED
client.go:607: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
client.go:607: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
client.go:607: [debug] sentry-db-check: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for sentry-db-check: MODIFIED
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded
helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: job failed: DeadlineExceeded
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:141
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:872
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:990
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:918
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
```

```
kubectl get job
NAME                        COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
sentry-db-check             0/1           8m30s      8m30s
templates-sentry-db-check   0/1           6d21h      6d21h
```

inspect job event. But I don't know.

```
kubectl describe job sentry-db-check
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From            Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate  8m49s  job-controller  Created pod: sentry-db-check-skvrs
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete  5m41s  job-controller  Deleted pod: sentry-db-check-skvrs
  Warning  DeadlineExceeded  5m41s  job-controller  Job was active longer than specified deadline
```

```
kubectl describe job templates-sentry-db-check
Events:           <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit values.yaml and increase activeDeadlineSeconds. Seems like the job sentry-db-check reaches timeout when trying to connect to other components. 1000 worked in my case.

```
hooks:
  enabled: true
  removeOnSuccess: true
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 1000
  shareProcessNamespace: false
```